# windows 8 stuck after loading menu

Tags: windows

I am using Hp pavilion g6 i5 processor. I recently installed windows 8 x64 in it.

It was working correctly. When today I 
just started the laptop I got stuck on the black screen with just a cursor. I can do nothing, even on a startup. I tried pressing F8 Esc ctrl+shift+esc to load task manager. But nothing happened.

Then I went to windows forum and I was told to install new window. But I am not able to use usb either, I have tried to use Usb but its not showing up anything I mean nothing is being done. All that I get is that black screen.

I have tried removing battery but its stuck somehow, can you guide me? Please..

Comment: Is it going through POST fine?

Comment: Yah everything goes fine but just desktop doesnt load fine! And it just gets stuck..

Comment: It could be 1 of a million problems with what we have best bet is to re-install windows or send it back to HP to get windows re-installed if you can't

Comment: Yup! Thats what I think about now. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix to the issue was somehow sick or even funny. The issue was with the battery. When I tried to remove the battery-->add the battery back-->Turn it on back = I got the same issue. But when I tried to run the laptop on the AC cable only (removed the battery) I got back the laptop running perfectly. Then I shut it down and added the battery back. Now I can run it in a great condition. Its pretty funny too. Now I will try to replace the battery obviously :D

Answer (score -1):

this likely cause by virus infected. You can try boot into safe mode or plug your hard drive into another computer to backup your data, then you can format and reinstall your windows from DOS

Comment: Ummm what ?? :o i never saw thay coming anywhere..its basically an issue in windows..